# Powershell script to change encoding alters accented characters

Tags: powershell, encoding, utf-8

We have some extracts that are being sent to us from a different system. The encoding keeps changing. We need to maintain that internally. Wrote a PowerShell script to change the encoding to UTF-8. But the accented characters are changed. The name Denaè changes to DenaÃ¨ I would like to retain the name as Denaè ? Any help would be much appreciated.

I would like to change the file to UTF-8 with the accented characters unchanged, using PowerShell. Is it possible?

vonPryz

Here is the code that i have right now

$Source =  'C:\Source'

$Destination =  'C:\Destination'

$Utf8NoBomEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding($False)

Remove-Item $Destination -Recurse -Force

foreach ($i in Get-ChildItem $Source -Recurse -Force) {
if ($i.PSIsContainer) {
continue
}

```
$path = $i.DirectoryName.Replace($Source, $Destination)
$name = $i.Fullname.Replace($Source, $Destination)

if ( !(Test-Path $path) ) {
    New-Item -Path $path -ItemType directory
}

$content = get-content $i.Fullname

if ( $content -ne $null ) {
    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($name, $content, $Utf8NoBomEncoding)
} else {
    Write-Host "No content from: $i"   
}
```

}

Comment: The substitution `è -> Ã¨` looks like the file is converted into plain text, so it's no longer Unicode. Show the relevant parts of code that processes the file with a [repro].

Comment: Powershell 5.1 get-content won't detect utf8 no bom without the "-encoding utf8" parameter.

Answer (score 0):

`Ã¨` characters **are** UTF-8 appearance of the character `è` *Latin Small Letter E With Grave* (codepoint `U+00E8`).

**Proof:**

```
[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes([char]'è') -join ', '
# 195, 168

[System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes([char[]]'Ã¨') -join ', '
# 195, 168

[char[]][System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes([char]'è') -join ''
# Ã¨
```